# Using UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER macro

Tags: c++, visual-studio, parameters, macros, compiler-warnings

I'm using \W4 warning level on Visual Studio and I'm writing a Windows program.

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
```

All these parameters are not used in my application, so I get warnings at compile time.

I know there are two ways of dealing with this:

1. Commenting parameters `HINSTANCE /*hInstance*/` ...
2. Using the `UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER` macro

   ```
   int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
   {
     UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hInstance);
     UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
     UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);
     UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(nCmdShow);
   ```

Which one is the correct one? Which one is the safer to use? Are there any problems with using the macro?

Comment: Both are rights, both are safes. It's a question of taste. What do you prefer?

Comment: @Gonmator is there a decrease of speed when using the macro?

Comment: No, Not when optimization are enabled (release). `UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(p)` macro is defined as `p = p;` This code avoid the warning but is discarded with basic optimization. In Debug builds, I'm not sure if that macro will generate any code. But you'll be not worry about performance in debug.

Comment: @Gonmator So for example, if I have "Maximize Speed (/O2)" I shouldn't have problem?

Comment: @Edouardo: No, absolutely no.

Comment: I'll use the commenting method on my personal project, but I think that in a team other programmers would understand better by using the macro. Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would prefer commenting the parameters.

The macro UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER is defined in winnt.h and therefore not portable.

And if later you do reference it, you might overlook to remove the macro.

Edit: With C++17 you can now use the [[maybe_unused]] attribute. This is useful for code depending on preprocessor macros:

```
void foo( [[maybe_unused]] int value )
{
#ifdef USE_VALUE
   useValue(value);
#endif
}
```

Now there won't be warnings even if USE_VALUE is undefined.

Comment: Even if it's not defined for other platforms, the macro can be easily defined for them: `#define UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(P) (P)`

Comment: Sorry for the late accept. Many years went by and I had totally forgot about this question. Thanks again!

Comment: @Millie Smith: while that is easily feasible (and ok), this is problematic since UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER needs to be available consistently on all platforms. Which will be the case on Win32 (rather implicit/always - this macro is "their" toolkit property...), but not everywhere else (explicit #include needed). Thus, annoying compile errors, all the time. Thus, best choose to create an explicitly "scoped"/"namespaced" different macro name which thus is required to be explicitly #include:d *consistently* on all platforms. Result: porting compile error inconsistency annoyance solved.

Answer (score 3):

I consider the name-removing version the first to go with. It can have a disadvantage to confuse the information system so tooltip shows the crippled version.  But healthy ones would use the declaration, where the names are there. (and for static and one-use things you should not have unused params, right?)

Otherwise it's matter of taste really.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, both are the correct ways to handle and do not introduce any unsafe-ness directly. However, the use of UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER can cause a maintenance issue because you need to remove the use of the macro if the parameter is used in the future updates, yet compilers do not warn that situation. To audit correct use of the macro, developers have to manually inspect that the parameters are still unused.

As others pointed out, cross-platform portability could be an issue too.

In C, it is not possible to remove the parameter name; hence the macro is the reasonable solution on the Windows platform, especially in Win32 programming.

Comment: Thanks for an updated answer after such a long time.