# #pragma warning does not work for catch statement

Tags: c++, warnings, pragma

In the following codes:

```
const int ME_ABORT_EXCEPTION = 1;

class CMyException
{
public:
    CMyException(int nErrorCode)
    : m_nErrorCode(nErrorCode)
    {
    }

    ~CMyException()
    {
    }

    int m_nErrorCode;   
};

void CTestExceptionDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    try
    {
        throw CMyException(ME_ABORT_EXCEPTION);
    }
#pragma warning(disable:4101)
    catch(CMyException& e)
    {
        ASSERT(e.m_nErrorCode == ME_ABORT_EXCEPTION);
    }
#pragma warning(default:4101)
}
```

I try to disable the compiler warning C4101 with #pragma, but it does not work. When compiling Release version, there will still be compiler warning. Why?

The warning message is:

```
warning C4101: 'e' : unreferenced local variable
```

Comment: Please explain what the warning is. Very few people memorize Microsoft's numerical codes.

Comment: @molbdnilo, OK, I have added the warning message.

Comment: You could just remove the variable name if you don't need it. `catch(CMyException&) {...}` is perfectly valid.

Comment: I can't reproduce this in VS 2017. What's your compiler version? (You really should fix this by not naming the exception, though. That solution works on all platforms.)

Comment: From memory, Microsoft docs say that, for some range of warning numbers, if a `#pragma warning` is in a function block, it doesn't have effect until after the function block.   I don't know offhand if C4101 is in that range, but it is a possibility.   In any event, rather than using a pragma (inherently a compiler-specific hook, that will often not work with other compilers) simply change the `catch` to `catch(CMyException &)`  (remove the name `e`).   Also, preferably, make it `const`.

Comment: @churill, I have posted my original codes to the post. As you can see, in Debug version, the variable e will still be used. But in Release version, there will be compiler warning. That is the reason why I cannot use catch(CMyException&) to catch the exception.

Comment: @molbdnilo, I am using VS2008.

Comment: @alancc Ahh, ok. It works find in VS2019. Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192224/using-unreferenced-parameter-macro) can be helpful. It offers some more information on the `UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER`-macro which you could use as workaround

Comment: `catch([[maybe_unused]]CMyException& e)` since C++17.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, the `C4101` warning works at *function scope*, so you have to disable it before/outside the function(s) you want to apply it to:

```cpp
#pragma warning(disable:4101)
void CTestExceptionDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    try
    {
        throw CMyException(ME_ABORT_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch (CMyException & e)
    {
        ASSERT(e.m_nErrorCode == ME_ABORT_EXCEPTION);
    }
}
#pragma warning(default:4101)
```

I've tested this in VS2010 and it works. In VS2017 and VS2019, the warning is also disabled as expected in your *original* code arrangement.